# SQL запрос на выборку из связных таблиц

Tags: c#, mysql, winforms, phpmyadmin

Приложения на WinForms, бд phpmyadmin.
Есть 3 таблицы `worker`, `shift`, `shift_days`. В последней лежат id_Worker, id_Shift и Day.

Теперь, когда нажимаю на ячейку компонента `DataGridWorker`, то передаю `id` в переменную `static_idWorker`.
После, открывается новая форма, где нужно выбрать в какой день у воркера будет смена. Когда щелкаем по дню, то открывается новая форма с `DataGridShift` которая отображает таблицу `shift` для выбора смены, например "Открытие 9:00 - 13:00". После чего Это все уходит в таблицу `shift_days`.
Проблема в том, что когда я пытаюсь снова открыть форму с выбором дней, чтобы посмотреть уже отмеченные дни, я получаю только первого попавшегося воркера. Т.Е. если `23.05.22` в смене стоит 2 человека, то будет отображаться только 1.
Запрос:

```
public void displaShifts()
{
    MySqlConnection connection = DataWorker.getConnection();
    String sql = "SELECT * FROM shift_days INNER JOIN worker ON shift_days.id_Worker = worker.id WHERE Day = ?";
    MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(sql, connection);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("Day", lbDays.Text + "/" + FrmShiftCalendar.static_monthShift + "/" + FrmShiftCalendar.static_yearShift);
    MySqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    if (reader.Read())
    {
        if(reader["id_Worker"].ToString() == FrmMain.static_idWorker)
        {
            lbShift.Text = "Смена";
            cardShift.color = Color.Green;
        }
    }
    reader.Dispose();
    cmd.Dispose();
    connection.Close();
}
```

Тут, наверное, бессмысленный inner join.
Но даже если я буду использовать обычный запрос

```
SELECT * FROM shift_days WHERE Day = ?
```

Выведется только 1 запись подходящая по условию.
Т.е. если у меня 25 числа стоят два воркера, она выведет одного, того, кто выше по таблице.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У Вас стоит условие `if(reader.Read())`. Из-за чего выбирается только одна строка. Чтобы это исправить замените его на цикл, как показано в [документации](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/retrieving-data-using-a-datareader). Например так:

```
while (reader.Read())
{
    if(reader["id_Worker"].ToString() == FrmMain.static_idWorker)
    {
        lbShift.Text = "Смена";
        cardShift.color = Color.Green;
    }
}
```

Comment: Боже, совсем не заметил. ty